# When scraping a website using Scrapy, how do I make sure all characters scrape properly?

Tags: character-encoding, web-scraping, character, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to scrape a website but some of the characters, such as apostrophes, do not scrape correctly nor are they consistently the same wrong character, i.e., I've had an apostrophe show up as multiple odd characters in my result set. How do I ensure that all characters scrape properly?

**Edit**

I am trying to scrape http://www.nowtoronto.com/music/listings/ with the following scraper:

```
import urlparse
import time
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
#from NT.items import NowTorontoItem
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class NowTorontoItem(Item):
    eventArtist = Field()
    eventTitle = Field()
    eventHolder = Field()
    eventDetails = Field()
    #venueName = Field()
    eventAddress = Field()
    eventLocality = Field()
    eventPostalCode = Field()
    eventPhone = Field()
    eventURL = Field()
    eventPrice = Field()
    eventDate = Field()
    internalURL = Field()

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "NTSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["nowtoronto.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.nowtoronto.com/music/listings/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        listings = selector.css("div.listing-item0, div.listing-item1")

        for listing in listings:
            item = NowTorontoItem()
            for body in listing.css('span.listing-body > div.List-Body'):
                item ["eventArtist"] = body.css("span.List-Name::text").extract()
                item ["eventTitle"] = body.css("span.List-Body-Emphasis::text").extract()
                item ["eventHolder"] = body.css("span.List-Body-Strong::text").extract()
                item ["eventDetails"] = body.css("::text").extract()
                #item ["internalURL"] = body.css("a::attr(href)").extract() 
                time.sleep(1)
            for body in listing.css('div.listing-readmore'):
                item ["internalURL"] = body.css("a::attr(href)").extract()   


            # yield a Request()
            # so that scrapy enqueues a new page to fetch
            detail_url = listing.css("div.listing-readmore > a::attr(href)")

            if detail_url:
                yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url,
                              detail_url.extract()[0]),
                              meta={'item': item},
                              callback=self.parse_details)
            else:
               yield item

    def parse_details(self, response):
        self.log("parse_details: %r" % response.url)
        selector = Selector(response)
        listings = selector.css("div.whenwhereContent")

        for listing in listings:
            for body in listing.css('tr:nth-child(1) td.small-txt.dkgrey-txt.rightInfoTD'):
                item = response.meta['item']
                #item ["eventLocation"] = body.css("span[property='v:location']::text").extract()
                #item ["eventOrganization"] = body.css("span[property='v:organization'] span[property='v:name']::text").extract()
                #item ["venueName"] = body.css("span[property='v:name']::text").extract()
                item ["eventAddress"] = body.css("span[property='v:street-address']::text").extract()
                item ["eventLocality"] = body.css("span[property='v:locality']::text").extract()
                item ["eventPostalCode"] = body.css("span[property='v:postal-code']::text").extract()
                item ["eventPhone"] = body.css("span[property='v:tel']::text").extract()
                item ["eventURL"] = body.css("span[property='v:url']::text").extract()

            item ["eventPrice"] = listing.css('tr:nth-child(2) td.small-txt.dkgrey-txt.rightInfoTD::text').extract()

            item ["eventDate"] = listing.css('span[content*="201"]::attr(content)').extract()       

            yield item
```

I am getting characters in some of the results like `Ã©e` and `Ã©`. These are supposed to be characters like é and ç.

**Edit 2**

I am not sure the issue is simply related to the file viewer I am using. When I open my first scrape in a text editor, an apostrophe is formatted as â€™ whereas in my second scrape, the same apostrophe (from the same text string) is formatted as —È.

Comment: Could you be more specific and show an example of the problem?

Comment: @alecxe Done and done

Comment: @zgall1 , you are probably exporting to CSV, and Scrapy default encoding of output file is UTF-8. The data you are getting is probably fine, but you need to tell your CSV viewer that the file is in UTF8. What tool or program are you using?

Comment: You are correct I am exporting to CSV. I am using Excel to view the data. However, the incorrect characters do not appear consistently as the same set of character strings if I do two different scrapes of the same data. How can that be if it is just an issue of the tool used to view the data?

Comment: @pault. Please see my second edit for an example.

Comment: It seems that Excel is actually what is breaking the encoding. When I open the file immediately after scraping in a simple text editor, the encoding is fine. If I open it up in Excel, make changes and save those changes and then re-open the file in a simple text editor, the encoding is broken. Any ideas as to a superior CSV viewer than Excel?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the data is actually fine but the encoding was broken when I opened and saved the file in Excel. I have switched to [Libre Office](http://www.libreoffice.org/), which specifically asks for the encoding of the document when it is being opened, and everything works fine.